# Sum coding doesn't seem to be working: the intercept is the mean of the 'reference' level rather than the grand mean of all levels

Tags: r, regression, refactoring

I am currently using the `robu()` function in R to run a meta-regression applying robust variance estimation.  This seems to be working ok.  However, I am interested using sum instead of treatment coding, so that I can compare each level of a factor with the grand mean (`dataset = Data_meta_REG, factor = memtype, levels = another`, episodic and working). This method is used in an existing paper.

I am new to R and so far have managed to piece things together from R Documentation and by searching various forums.  Unfortunately, when I run the analysis, the intercept doesn't seem to be the grand mean, and is instead the mean of the level allocated as the reference (e.g. if I swap the order of the levels, a different value for the intercept is returned, whereas if it was the grand mean it should be the same).

So I've hit a bit of a brick wall and wondered if anyone could please highlight my error(s)? I'm hoping it's something simple I am getting wrong! Nonetheless, it's quite frustrating as it is preventing me from continuing my work, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
library("metafor")
library("dplyr")
library("robumeta")

# Setting memtype as factor
Data_meta_REG_contrasts = Data_meta_REG %>% mutate(memtype = as.factor(memtype))

                                
# Setting contrast using function contr.sum
contrasts(Data_meta_REG_contrasts$memtype) = contr.sum(3)

# Regression model using robu() function 
res_memtype <- robu(effect.size ~ factor(memtype), data = Data_meta_REG_contrasts, 
                    studynum = study, var.eff.size = var.eff.size, 
                    modelweights = "CORR", small = TRUE) 
print(res_memtype)

# Output with ‘another’ as missing variable/’reference’/’intercept’
                         Estimate StdErr t-value  dfs P(|t|>) 95% CI.L 95% CI.U
1            X.Intercept.   0.5274  0.671   0.786 2.21   0.507    -2.11     3.16
2 factor.memtype.episodic  -0.0852  0.680  -0.125 3.51   0.907    -2.08     1.91
3  factor.memtype.working  -0.2076  0.702  -0.296 3.85   0.783    -2.19     1.77

# Output with ‘working’ as missing variable/’reference’/’intercept’
                          Estimate StdErr t-value   dfs P(|t|>) 95% CI.L 95% CI.U Sig
1            X.Intercept.    0.320  0.208   1.539  8.52   0.160   -0.154    0.794    
2 factor.memtype.episodic    0.122  0.238   0.515 15.62   0.614   -0.382    0.627    
3    factor.memtype.other    0.208  0.702   0.296  3.85   0.783   -1.771    2.186
```

If I run the analysis with removing the intercept (`effect.size ~ factor(memtype) -1`), I get all three individual level means.

```
                      Estimate StdErr t-value   dfs P(|t|>) 95% CI.L 95% CI.U Sig
1  factor.memtype.another    0.527  0.671   0.786  2.21 0.50716   -2.110    3.164    
2 factor.memtype.episodic    0.442  0.116   3.823 10.22 0.00323    0.185    0.699 ***
3  factor.memtype.working    0.320  0.208   1.539  8.52 0.16011   -0.154    0.794
```

Please let me know if further clarification of my question in required.

Many thanks
Lucy

Comment: I do not see why you cannot use one of the example datasets to illustrate this problem. Them we could see what coding strategy you have been using. At the moment there's no way to do any debugging.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the heads up.  I will take a look at these and try to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I cobbled together an example and I do get different estimates with a factor that has sum contrast attribute versus treatment contrasts model when the Intercept term is in the model but not when the `-1` form of the formula is used. I'm wondering if the problem is in the labeling but the math machinery is working.? I think the way forward would be to construct an example in code for which you you will know the correct answer and then run models in that data.

Comment: @IRTFM Thank you so much for taking the time to test this.  Following your suggestion, I also just ran the code on a simple dataset and found both sum and treatment contrasts to work as expected.  However, this was only the case for a basic linear regression model (lm).  The robu() model seems to ignore the set contrasts, so I must have the wrong code for incorporating sum coding with robust variance estimation.  Thank you for helping me to identify where the problem lies!

Comment: @IRTFM It has worked!! I had a play around with the robu() labels, and as it turns out, where I have effect.size ~ factor(memtype), removing the word 'factor' returns the correct sum coded outputs (i.e. intercept as grand mean).  I no longer get the individual labels in the output table rows (e.g. memtype1 instead of episodic) but the numbers work so I am happy! Thanks again - very grateful :)

Comment: You should write up your efforts as an answer below and give yourself a checkmark after an appropriate waiting period which I believe is 2 days. I could have published my efforts using the SATcoaching dataset but I think your efforts might be more complete.